# while list is empty, check again if the list is empty, if list is not empty iterate for loop and print it

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
my_list = []
#my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
while not my_list:
    print("Check Again")
    if my_list:
        for i in my_list:
            print("Loop ",i)
        break
```

I tried above code with my_list = [1,2,3] which should probably print all the 3. But i got below error.

- Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
  Press Enter to exit terminal

Comment: Why would you expect `not my_list` to be true, when the list does contain things?

Comment: Really only need `for i in my_list: print("Loop ",i)`.  If it is empty nothing will print.  There's nothing here that would ever change `my_list` so the `while` and `if` just preventing anything from printing.  If the list is empty, the `while` will be an infinite loop.

Comment: If my_list is empty you will output "Check again" indefinitely. If my_list is not empty you will get no output and your program will terminate without error

Answer (score 1):

The while loop only runs if the list is empty. The if statement only runs if it is not empty. I'm not sure why you have the `while` loop at all probably you just want the if statement, or

```
if not my_list:
    print("Check Again")
else:
    if my_list:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will run indefinitely until `my_list` is empty,which it will never be because you initialize it with `[1, 2, 3]`. This leads to an infinite loop, causing the process to exit. That why you get the error.`Process Exited`

If you simple want to print all the elements in the `my_list` use a `for loop`.